# Font too small in Chrome URL address

Tags: 15.10, google-chrome

The font in Chrome is fine except the url address which looks really tiny. I just switched from Gnome to Ubuntu 15.10 and Chrome looked just fine in Gnome.

Does anyone know what is going on ?

See this picture of Chrome:

[image]

Tabs' and pages' font looks fine and readable.

Comment: Errrmmmm... Excuse me... Did you do something in order to get such effect? Sorry I can't provide an answer so far but I'd like to know what you did before in order to get that font size for two purposes: 1. To provide some help for your situation. 2. For reproducing the case on my own web browser. :D Thank you!

Comment: @Yahyaotaif What version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: I actually didn't do anything. It looked like this when I installed it. However, I set the zoom to 150. I have Version 51.0.2704.63 on ubuntu 15.10. Also, Chromium looks good and doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to switch back to gnome.

Comment: This is a [Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1074660) that you can vote on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's the new chrome, ever since v50 update it's like that. Nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Damn `sudo apt-get upgrade`!   XD

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall Chrome and restart your PC. Everything should work fine. Just a small glitch,  nothing else. Make sure to remove it completely and reinstall from original PPA.

Comment: I actually reinstalled it with restart but no luck. I even upgraded to 16.04 but the same issue continues.

Comment: Ah...the problem must be system  scaling. Have you changed the dpi of screen?